# Replace string of class of button by class so that only one button is filled in using bootstrap buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using bootstrap buttons, and in this case I have 5 different buttons with 5 different classes. When one of the buttons is clicked on, I want it to be the only one filled in, and the others to only be the outline. Here is how I currently do it:

```js
$(".canvas_btn").on("click",function(){
  for(var i = 0; i < $(".canvas_btn").length; i++){
    document.getElementById($(".canvas_btn")[i].id).className = document.getElementById($(".canvas_btn")[i].id).className.replace("btn-outline-","btn-");
    document.getElementById($(".canvas_btn")[i].id).className = document.getElementById($(".canvas_btn")[i].id).className.replace("btn-","btn-outline-");
  }
  document.getElementById(this.id).className = document.getElementById(this.id).className.replace("btn-outline","btn");   
});
```

```html
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="btn btn-outline-info     canvas_btn" align="left"  id="new_text_btn">Text</button>
<button class="btn btn-outline-secondary  canvas_btn" align="left"  id="new_audio_btn">Audio</button>
<button class="btn btn-outline-success   canvas_btn" align="left"  id="new_image_btn">Image</button>
<button class="btn btn-outline-danger   canvas_btn" align="left"  id="new_video_btn">Video</button>
<button class="btn btn-outline-warning   canvas_btn" align="left"  id="new_input_btn">Input</button>
```

It feels a bit odd the way I've done it - is there a more elegant way to do it? A way to use jQuery to make it tidier would be great!

I'm also not sure how I'm causing the error in the console - I think it's to do with the bootstrap script I call in, so don't know what I can do about that.

Comment: Bootstrap has [radio buttons](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/buttons/#checkbox-and-radio-buttons) that do what you're wanting.

Answer (score 2):

Here's how I refactored your code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $(".canvas_btn").on("click", function () {

        var idOfClickedElem = $(this).attr('id');
        $.each($('.canvas_btn'), function () {
            if (idOfClickedElem === $(this).attr('id')) {
                $(this).attr('class', getFilledClassName($(this).attr('class')))
            }
            else {
                $(this).attr('class', getOutlineClassName($(this).attr('class')))
            }
        });

    });

    function getOutlineClassName(currentClasses) {
        return currentClasses.replace("btn-outline-", "btn-").replace("btn-", "btn-outline-")
    }

    function getFilledClassName(currentClasses) {
        return currentClasses.replace("btn-outline", "btn")
    }


});
```

Instead of mixing jQuery and regular JavaScript selectors, I just used jQuery. I'm not a huge fan of the contents of `getOutlineClassName(currentClasses)` and `getFilledClassName(currentClasses)`, but it's certainly less code than the way I probably would have written it if I had done so from scratch -- which would be to make a `switch` on the element's id and return the correct classes as a string accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

As was already mentioned, the code mixes a lot of jQuery methods with plain vanilla DOM access JS methods. If you are going to use jQuery then why not use other jQuery methods? I was initially thinking [`.toggleClass()`](https://api.jquery.com/toggleClass) would work to simplify the logic on adding/removing class names, but because they are each somewhat unique that doesn't appear to work.

It is wise to store DOM lookups in a variable and then reference the variable instead of repeatedly querying the DOM. For instance, `$('.canvas_btn')` can be stored once the DOM is ready (using [`$(function() {...}`](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery3) (formerly [`.ready()`](https://api.jquery.com/ready)):

```
$(function() { //DOM ready callback
  var canvasBtns = $('.canvas_btn');
```

Then use that variable instead of `$('.canvas_btn')`:

```
canvasBtns.click(function() { //click handler
  canvasBtns.each(function() { //iterate over canvas buttons
```

And as that last code snippet alludes to, use [`.each()`](https://api.jquery.com/each) (similar to [`Array.prototype.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/foreach) but for jQuery collections) to iterate over the buttons.

As far as updating the class name for each button, what you really want to do is remove `-outline` if the id matches the button that was clicked, or add it if it doesn't already have that. So in the rewritten code below, the id of the button that was clicked is stored in a variable, and then that is passed to the `.each` handler, which uses a [partially applied function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind#Partially_applied_functions) with [`Function.bind()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind#Partially_applied_functions).

```
canvasBtns.click(function() {
  var clickedId = $(this).attr('id');
  canvasBtns.each(toggleOutlineClass.bind(null, clickedId));
});
```

Then that function `toggleOutlineClass` will accept first `clickedId`, followed by the other arguments passed by [`.each()`](https://api.jquery.com/each):

> ```
> Integer index, Element element
> ```

Then that function can either remove the `-outline` string if it is the item clicked (based on whether `clickedId` matches `$(btn).attr('id')`) or add that string if the class name doesn't already have it.

```
function toggleOutlineClass(clickedId, index, btn) {
  var className = $(btn).attr('class');
  if (clickedId === $(btn).attr('id')) {
    $(btn).attr('class', className.replace('btn-outline-', 'btn-'));
  } else if (className.indexOf('btn-outline-') < 0) {
    $(btn).attr('class', className.replace('btn-', 'btn-outline-'));
  }
}
```

A lot of the tips above are based on information in [this article](https://ilikekillnerds.com/2015/02/stop-writing-slow-javascript/). I suggest reading that for more tips.

```js
$(function() { //DOM ready callback
  var canvasBtns = $('.canvas_btn');
  canvasBtns.click(function() {
    var clickedId = $(this).attr('id');
    canvasBtns.each(toggleOutlineClass.bind(null, clickedId));
  });

  function toggleOutlineClass(clickedId, index, btn) {
    var className = $(btn).attr('class');
    if (clickedId === $(btn).attr('id')) {
      $(btn).attr('class', className.replace('btn-outline-', 'btn-'));
    } else if (className.indexOf('btn-outline-') < 0) {
      $(btn).attr('class', className.replace('btn-', 'btn-outline-'));
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="btn btn-outline-info     canvas_btn" align="left" id="new_text_btn">Text</button>
<button class="btn btn-outline-secondary  canvas_btn" align="left" id="new_audio_btn">Audio</button>
<button class="btn btn-outline-success   canvas_btn" align="left" id="new_image_btn">Image</button>
<button class="btn btn-outline-danger   canvas_btn" align="left" id="new_video_btn">Video</button>
<button class="btn btn-outline-warning   canvas_btn" align="left" id="new_input_btn">Input</button>
```